# How to connect with Flash One 1x EVDO CDMA (type st804) Modem

Tags: usb-modem, cdma

How to connect with Flash One 1x EVDO Modem? I cannot connecting with this modem. So, i cannot do apt-get updates. Please, i need it.

Comment: whats the output of lsusb ?

Comment: st-804 type of modem. I am newbie of Ubuntu/Linux.

Answer (score 0):

connect the modem to your usb port . then click at network applet that will exists at top panel of your desktop . after clicking selectedit  connections . then there create a connection to your modem at mobile broadband with new option . give enough feta details like apn and all. then save it and click at  your network applets and select your connection .

Comment: Doing from mobile . some one please put in format . thank you .

Comment: It's doesn't work.

Comment: whats the problem you're getting ?

Comment: Ubuntu don't detect my device.

Comment: connect the modem to your usb port . then click at network applet that will exists at top panel of your desktop . after clicking selectedit connections . then there create a connection to your modem at mobile broadband with new option . give enough feta details like apn and all. then save it and click at your network applets and select your connection .

This step isn't work. My modem not detected.

Comment: give me output of lsusb